# Which episodes show the battle between Naruto with Madara and Tobi?

Tags: naruto

I want to rewatch Naruto's fight with Madara but there are so many episodes and 20% of them are fillers.

Which episodes show the battle between Naruto with Madara and Tobi?

Answer (score 2):

Naruto starts fighting with Madara during episode 392 of *Shippuuden*.

This battle happens during the [Birth of the Ten-Tails' Jinchūriki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Birth_of_the_Ten-Tails%27_Jinch%C5%ABriki) arc, which spans over the following episodes:

- 378 to 388
- 391 to 393
- 414 to 421
- 424 to 427

Of these mentioned episodes, most are canon with the exception of the following, although some of these might still be worth watching as they do contain some canon content. Those are marked as such. [(source)](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden):

- 388 Mostly filler
- 415 Mostly canon ***← should watch this one***
- 416 Filler
- 417 Mostly filler
- 419 Mostly filler
- 427 Filler